# Order in which to wash face, hands and feet

Tags: priorities, hands-fingers, face, showering-bathing

A halocho sheet given out in my shul says that there is an order to washing (e.g. on Erev Shabbos) – first face then right hand, left hand and finally feet. The source is given as מחזיק ברכה ר״ס, ג.

I had always thought that פניו ידיו ורגליו was a phrase but not a specified order because it is difficult to imagine washing the face before the hands.

Are there other sources which discuss the order of washing hands, face and feet?

Comment: Perhaps ידיו means arms, as in "...לאות על ידך...".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the issue is based on the Gemorah Mesechtas Shabbos 61A.

The Aruch Hashulchan 260:3 also gives  that order (he says that if you are washing your  whole body your heart goes after  your head)

The Shulchan Orech HaRav says you start with the head and then just go to the right side of the body.

This isn't to say that all poskim agree you need to wash your body in a certain order. (That is for your LOR) It's just to say that this issue is mentioned in other sources and based on a Gemorah.

Comment: Rema in Darchei Moshe O.C. 2 says לא ראיתי מדקדקים בזה

Comment: @Alex, can you please post a link to the DarcheiMoshe in the Rema - I don't see it.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x6

Comment: @Alex Thank you. That would be another answer.